# alpinejs Checkbox checked on init or based on x-modal not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, alpine.js

When loading alpinejs it uncheckes all checkboxes, i don't know why it is doing so but it is.

```
<div x-data="{ colors: [orange] }">
    <input type="checkbox" value="red" x-model="colors">
    <input type="checkbox" value="orange" x-model="colors" :checked="colors.includes('orange')">
    <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" x-model="colors">
    <div class="pt-4">Colors: <span x-text="colors">orange,red,yellow</span></div>
</div>
```

So when loading the code above I need orange to be checked, but it doesn't. does somebody knows whats going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add single quote in the array `['orange']` and you don't need the `:checked...`

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.3.4/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ colors: ['orange'] }">
    <input type="checkbox" value="red" x-model="colors">
    <input type="checkbox" value="orange" x-model="colors">
    <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" x-model="colors">
    <div class="pt-4">Colors: <span x-text="colors"></span></div>
</div>
```